# Python/Tkinter: fine points about super init and self

Tags: python, tkinter

Following is very simple code to create a frame and label as a class:

```
class FrameWithLabel(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(self, parent)
        self.label = tk.Label(self)
```

I have two questions:

1. In an earlier post, it was explained to me why the super init was required (in this case, referring to the tk.Frame), and that without the super init, the Frame widget would not be correctly initialized. If that's the case, then why can the Label simply be passed in as self.label without a similar super init type initialization of a tk Label? There is obviously something I am still not grasping about super init.
2. This is a very minor point, but I don't like the way that referring to the Frame and Label are asymmetrical. That is, if I wanted to change an attribute of the frame from the main app, I would use FrameWithLabel.configure(bg="red"). But if I wanted to change the label, I would have to use FrameWithLabel.label.configure(bg="red"). I would rather that the Frame and Label occupied the same level in the code so that I would be referring to FrameWithLabel.frame and FrameWithLabel.label. In that case, the class would have to be initialized with something other than the Frame widget. If that's possible, what would that element be? I have tried "class SomeClassName(tk):" and it doesn't work. Also, if there is an element that could be used in this way, would a super init line be required?

My apologies if question 2 seems trivial, since the above code works just fine, but I'm really trying to drill down to how all of this stuff works under the hood, and make my classes as intuitive and user-friendly as possible. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why can the Label simply be passed in as self.label without a similar super init type initialization of a tk Label?

It is because you aren't subclassing the `Label` class. The label you create in `__init__` is just a normal label. You only need to call `super` when you're creating a subclass of a widget.

> if I wanted to change the label, I would have to use FrameWithLabel.label.configure(bg="red"). I would rather that the Frame and Label occupied the same level in the code so that I would be referring to FrameWithLabel.frame and FrameWithLabel.label.

This question is unclear. You *do* refer to the label with `FrameWithLabel.label`. It's not clear what you want instead.

If you want to be able to do something like `frame_with_label.configure(label="the label")` then you'll have to create a custom `configure` method. It might look something like this:

```
class FrameWithLabel(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.label = tk.Label(self)
        self.label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    def configure(self, **kwargs):
        if "label" in kwargs:
            value = kwargs.pop("label")
            self.label.configure(text=value)

        # call the built-in configure method for the other arguments
        super().configure(**kwargs)
```

With the above, you can set the label like this:

```
labelframe = FrameWithLabel(root)
labelframe.configure(label="Hello, world")
```

Comment: Many thanks. The answer to the first question is clear. But what I'm asking in the second question is how I can initialize the class using some element other than the frame widget, so that both the frame and the label are added later in the class. So instead of 
class ClassName(tk.Frame): it would be class ClassName(some other element): and then the frame and widget could be added later.

Comment: @fmex: this is why you shouldn't ask more than one thing at a time. If you don't want to add a frame, then don't inherit from anything at all. `Class FrameWithLabel()`. You then don't need to call `super`. However, it won't be a widget that you can use like a widget, it'll just be a normal python object. When dealing with widgets, it's best to inherit from `Frame` so that you can add it to the UI.

Comment: my apologies. I sincerely appreciate the advice you have provided me, and will be more careful in future.